# Select to choose the value of a boolean variable

Tags: angular, form-control

How can I create a dynamic input for a true-false selection? I tried the following code, but it doesn't produce what I want.

[image]

This is the initial state of the select and it's correct.

[image]

But after the change I get this, as if the second interpolation fails to evaluate the opposite value of user.enabled.

[image]

What I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The option value should be always the same in each 
What you have to do is determinate the selected value instead.

```
<select class="form-control" #enabled (change)="changeEnabledState(user, enabled.value)">
    <option value="true" [attr.selected]="user.enabled ? 'selected' : null">True</option>
    <option value="false" [attr.selected]="!user.enabled ? 'selected' : null">False</option>
</select>
```

This is a simple select with 2 options, but in other select maybe you want to use a ngFor for  and evaluate wich is the selected